# Editing metadata in the order admin page WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I have a custom WooCommerce payment gateway that saves metadata using:

`$order->update_meta_data('_example_data', esc_attr($_POST['_example_data']));`.

And is then displayed in the admin order page, and made editable, using the following:

```
// In constructor
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details',  array($this, 'display_payment_type_order_edit_pages'), 10, 1);
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', array($this, 'save_order_custom_field_meta'));


public function display_payment_type_order_edit_pages($order) {
    $example_data = $order->get_meta('_example_data');
    
    echo '<br class="clear" />';
    echo '<h4>Example Details <a href="#" class="edit_address">Edit</a></h4>';

    // Non-edit display.
    echo '<div class="address">';
    echo '<p><strong>' . __('Example Data') . ':</strong> ' . $example_data . '</p>';
            
    echo '</div>';
    
    echo '<div class="edit_address">';
    
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
                'id' => '_example_data',
                'label' => 'Example Data:',
                'value' => $example_data,
                'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide'
            ));
            
    echo '</div>';
}


function save_order_custom_field_meta($post_id) {
    
    if (isset($_POST['_example_data']))
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_example_data', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_example_data']));
    
}
```

The metadata saves correctly from the checkout, it's displayed correctly and the fields come up when you start to edit. However, the metadata doesn't seem to be saving after editing the order.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
I noticed some strange interactions while trialing some other features on a clean install of WP and WC, and I narrowed it down (kinda) to the class not being instantiated in the traditional way.

i.e. I am doing it like this:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_my_payment_gateway', 11);

function init_my_payment_gateway()
{

    class My_Payment_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway
    {
    // Rest of plugin here.
```

As apposed to the regular way of:

```
$my_class = new My_Payment_Gateway();
```

Additionally, I have also found that adding that action like so

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', array('my_payment_gateway', 'save_order_custom_field_meta'));
```

executes the function when the hook is fired; with an error of course (running non-static in a static way). So it seems adding the action within the plugin file causes it not to work?

Finally, if I see what functions are attached to the hook using `$wp_filter['woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta'];` I can actually see that `save_order_custom_field_meta` is attached. Yet it does not execute when the hook is run (confirmed with logging, breakpoints, etc).

Comment: I'm starting to think this behavior is happening due to the plugin initialisation using the `plugins_loaded` hook. I'm noticing any hook that redirects afterwards, such as `woocommerce_process_shop_order_met`a or `woocommerce_save_account_details`, doesn't execute the given function. This is true whether `add_action` is being used within the class constructor one of its functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your code first function doesn't display your editable field and you are making things more complicated than they should be. Try the following instead:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details',  'display_custom_editable_field_on_admin_orders' );
function display_custom_editable_field_on_admin_orders( $order ) {
    
    echo '<br class="clear" />
    <div class="example_data_wrapper">';
    
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => '_example_data',
        'label' => __('Example Data:'),
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide'
    ) );
            
    echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'save_order_custom_field_meta' );
function save_order_custom_field_meta( $post_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['_example_data']) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_example_data', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_example_data']) );
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

If you want to use the code in a **plugin within a Class**, you can use the following in a plugin file:

```php
/*
Plugin Name: Admin Order Editable field
Plugin URI: 
Description: Your shipping method plugin
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Me
Author URI: 
*/

if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Some_Class' ) ) {

    class WC_Some_Class {

        // In the constructor

        public function __construct() {
            # Your settings below to be defined
            
            $this->text_domain = 'my_text_domain'; // The domain name
            $this->meta_key    = '_example_data'; // The field Id or field slug
            $this->label_name  = __('Example Data', $this->text_domain ); // Field label

            # The hooks to be triggered
            
            add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details',  array( $this, 'display_custom_editable_field_on_admin_orders' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', array( $this, 'save_order_custom_field_meta' ) );
        }

        // Outside the constructor

        public function display_custom_editable_field_on_admin_orders( $order ) {
            echo '<br class="clear" />
            <div class="example_data_wrapper">';

            woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
                'id'            => $this->meta_key,
                'label'         => $this->label_name . ':',
                'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide'
            ) );

            echo '</div>';
        }

        public function save_order_custom_field_meta( $post_id ) {
            if ( isset($_POST[$this->meta_key]) )
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_example_data', sanitize_text_field($_POST[$this->meta_key]) );
        }
    }

    $some_class = new WC_Some_Class();
}
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I implemented your changes, which were nearly identical to one of my previous attempts. However, the data still doesn't save when edited in the admin order page and I press enter.

I've revised the code above to reflect the changes I've made. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @Tym I have tested that on last WooCommerce version and my code works properly, saving the custom field value when pressing "update" on admin single order pages. So I can't guess what is making trouble in your case.

Comment: I'm not sure either... 

The fields are appearing in the admin order edit page, they are being populated with the correct metadata (that was sent on checkout), their ID's are correct (inspecting element). But when the order is edited, the data is not updated, even if I just put something like `update_post_meta($post_id, '_example_data', 'test data replace');` as the function under the `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` hook. 

It feels as though that hook isn't triggering when the order is edited. I'm on `WooCommerce version 4.5.2`.

Comment: Yep! Just confirmed - by using the WooCommerce Logger `wc_get_logger();` and `logger->debug( 'example', $context );` I can see that `save_order_custom_field_meta` is not being called when an order is edited. However, the I can make the logger go off by putting it in other places; just to confirm its not a fault of the logger.

Comment: @Tym Sorry but it's called each time an order is edited… So there is something wrong in your case as this hook works and is triggered on last woocommerce version.

Comment: Yeah I'm very confused then. If I put that code exactly as is, into a 'Snippet', it works. However, running from my plugin php file, it does not. Have tried in a number of different ways. Can you confirm if running it from a plugin file (not from functions.php) works for you? I am on the latest version of WooCommerce as well. And if its still a unique error on my end - what, in your experience, could stop a hook from running like this?

Comment: @Tym I didn't try it in a plugin file… If you are using a plugin file, you should provide all the code of that plugin as an addition in at the end of your question... Plugin's code can be done in very different ways…

Comment: Strange - I received it; and have replied.

Comment: @Tym received… It's something else…